# Find bound for inverse of linear map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $B:H\times H\to \mathbb F$ a sesquilinear form, where $\mathbb F $ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
Suppose $B$ is bounded, i.e. there is some $c>0$ such that $\vert B(x,y)\vert \le c\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert \forall x,y\in H$. Then one can show that there exists one(!) linear mapping $T:H\to H$ with $B(x,y)=\langle x,Ty\rangle$ for all $x,y\in H$ and $\Vert T\Vert \le c$ . Assume there exists some $ 0<c_0\le c$ such that for all $x\in X$ holds $$\operatorname{Re}(B(x,x))\ge c_0\Vert x\Vert^2.$$

> Show T is boundedly invertible with $\Vert T^{-1}\Vert \le \frac{1}{c_0}$

I do not see how to start here. Probably one first has to show that $T$ is injective and surjective. 
Injectivity is clear. Let $x \in \ker(T)$. Then, $$c_0\Vert x\Vert^2=\operatorname{Re}(B(Tx,x))=\operatorname{Re}(\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\operatorname{Re}(\Vert Tx\Vert^2)=\Vert Tx \Vert^2$$
Righthandside is zero, lefthand side is zero iff $x=0$. Thus the kernel is trivial. Further one can show that $T$ is surjective, too. So $T^{-1}$ exists.

**Question:** How can one proceed then with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the boundedness part of the conclusion.

You can write $$c_0 \|x\|^2 \leq \operatorname{Re}(\langle x, Tx \rangle) \leq \|x\| \|Tx\|$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. This then implies that $\|x\| \leq c_0^{-1} \|Tx\|$. Taking $x = T^{-1}y$ will give you that $\|T^{-1} y \| \leq c_0^{-1} \|y\|$ which gives the boundedness part of the conclusion.